# Service inside docker container stops after some time

Tags: python, rest, nginx, docker

I have deployed a rest service inside a docker container using uwsgi and nginx.
When I run this python flask rest service inside docker container, for first one hour service works fine but after sometime somehow nginx and rest service stops for some reason.

Has anyone faced similar issue?
Is there any know fix for this issue?

Comment: you might investigate some tools like [ptrace/strace & friends](http://jvns.ca/blog/2014/04/20/debug-your-programs-like-theyre-closed-source/)

Answer (score 3):

Consider doing a `docker ps -a` to get the stopped container's identifier.
`-a` here just means listing **all** of the containers you got on your machine.

Then do `docker inspect` and look for the `LogPath` attribute. 
Open up the container's log file and see if you could identify the root cause on why the process died inside the container. (You might need root permission to do this)

**Note:** A process can die because of anything, e.g. code fault

If nothing suspicious is presented in the log file then you might want to check on the `State` attribute. Also check the `ExitCode` attribute to see if you can work backwards to see which line of your application could have exited using that code.

Also check the `OOMKilled` flag, if this is true then it means your container could be killed due to `out of memory` error.

Well if you still can't figure out why then you might need to add more logging into your application to give you more insight on why it died.

Comment: My container is still running fine but the service that was running inside the container has stopped.

Comment: So I assume your process is still up and running it is still just it stopped serving requests? Then I suspect it is more of an application specific problem than docker. Recommend adding some debug statements into your application to see if you can get any hints out from them or not.